# Why can't I make a char bound to the unicode castle character in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, syntax

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a = '∀';
        System.out.println(a);
        char castle = '';
        System.out.println(castle);
    }
}
```

I can make a char for the upside down A just fine, but when I try to make the castle char it gets 3 compile errors. Why?

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:5: unclosed character literal
        char castle = '';
                      ^
A.java:5: illegal character: \57159
        char castle = '';
                        ^
A.java:5: unclosed character literal
        char castle = '';
                         ^
3 errors
```

Comment: whats that ^ under every character? You put that?

Comment: @MrD That's javac pointing out where the error is.

Comment: [fileformat.info tells you how to type this:](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3f0/index.htm) `"\uD83C\uDFF0"`

Comment: lol why did some1 thumbs up my comment it was idiotic

Comment: Create a string with just that one character in it and then print out the length of the string.

Comment: @millimoose: ...except that the character in the OP's post is actually [U+1D347](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d347/index.htm), or `"\uD834\uDF47"` using UTF-16 surrogates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect that the castle character does not fit in a single `char`, but rather, requires an `int` code point.  In that case, you could use it in a `String` literal, but not as a `char`.

The Javadoc for `Character` states:

> The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value.

So my guess would be that that character requires more than 16 bits, so it would need to be treated as an `int` code point.

Comment: his code point is 0x1d347. Java doesn't let you put any character with a point above 0xffff, probably because java chars aren't unicode code points, they're utf-16 words...

Answer (score 2):

If your source code file contains non-ascii characters (as does this file), you need to ensure that `javac` reads it with the proper encoding, otherwise it will default to an encoding that is possibly not the one in which it was saved.

So, if you saved your file in `UTF-8` from your editor, you can compile it using:

```
javac -encoding utf8 A.java
```

Note that you can also use the unicode codepoint instead of the actual character, this makes the code compilable without the `-encoding` directive:

```
char a = '\u2200';              // The codepoint for the ∀ character
String castle = "\ud834\udf47"; // Being a high-surrogate char, the castle cannot fit a single 16 bit char
```

Comment: The castle is not a high surrogate character. High surrogates (now called leading surrogates) are the values in the range D800–DBFF. \uD834 is a high surrogate. The castle is just a non-BMP character.

Comment: You're right, the comment was poorly worded. The castle is in a supplementary plane, and must be represented with a surrogate pair (2 16bit characters) rather than a single char.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows:

- Create a new empty *Text Document* anywhere and copy-past  inside the text document.
- Close it and right click >> Properties >> in General tab see the *Size* it's **2**-byte.

As you see it's 2-byte you need to use two characters.
You probably want to read about  [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 internally.  All Java characters are two bytes long, not one.  This isn't C.  The problem isn't that it's two bytes, but that it's more than two bytes and Java doesn't handle characters which are represented by surrogate pairs in UTF-16.